# Converting an integer input to hexadecimal in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, int, hex, mips

I am writing a program in MIPS to convert an integer input by the user to hex and then output it. For some reason, no matter what I put in, the syscall only outputs 0x which is what I put in the answer space at the beginning. What am I doing wrong?

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter an integer number: "
answer: .space 8
.text
.globl main

main:
        la $a0, prompt1     #prompt user for integer
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        la $a1, answer      # load the address of answer into $a1
        addi $t0, $zero, 48 #set $t0 to 48
            sb $t0, 0($a1)          #store 48 at location 0 in $a1
            addi $t0, $0, 120       #set $t0 equal to 120
            sb $t0, 1($a1)          #store 120 at location 1 in $a1
            addi $a1, $a1, 4

            li $v0, 5       #allow for input of integer
        syscall
        add $a0, $v0, $zero #add the input to the $a0 register
        jal print_hex

        la $a0, answer
        li $v0, 4
        syscall         #print out hex answer to console

        j main


print_hex:
        andi $t0, $a0, 0xf
        addi $a1, $a1, 4

        ble $t0, 10, lessThanTen        
        addi $t0, $t0, 39   
    lessThanTen:
        addi $t0, $t0, 48
        sb $t0, 0($a1)
        srl $a0, $a0, 4
        bne $a0, $zero, print_hex
    done:
        jr $ra
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but adding `4` to `$a1` seems suspicious. If that's your text buffer, you want to add `1`. PS: learn to use a debugger to step through your code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ah you are correct! I forgot I was storing bytes and not storing words! Thank you for that @Jester

Comment: related: [MIPS Assembly: Convert from Integer to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19370600) and [Convert integer to its hexidecimal value to print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4363411)

Comment: **[Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37153381) has working code.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIPS Assembly: Convert from Integer to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370600/mips-assembly-convert-from-integer-to-hexadecimal)