# How to convert int to hex char in MIPS?

Tags: int, hex, mips

I'm trying to convert an int (0-15) to hex char (0-F) and just can't figure out how to do this simply, any ideas to help push me in the right direction?

Comment: If the number is between 0 and 9, add 48. If it is between 10 and 15, add 65. Also, take a look at an ASCII table...

Comment: why would I add 65 and not 55? If I'm starting at 10, to get to 65, shouldn't I add 55?

Comment: yes, you have to add 55 instead of 65 when the number is between 10 and 15, so that you get an ASCII code in the range 'A'-'F'.

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert integer to its hexidecimal value to print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4363411)

Comment: Or better, [Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37153381) has working code.